# isomorphisms are exactly the morphisms that take colimit cocones to colimit cocones

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, morphism

I would like to understand why isomorphisms are exactly the morphisms that take colimit cocones to colimit cocones. I believe that both directions are easy but they are not immediate to me. Which direction is trivial ? I ask this question just to be safe in preservation of colimits by functors.

For a hint what I mean please see the snippet below; $h$ must be iso:

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, this is very false. E.g. any left adjoint preserves colimits, but most left adjoints aren't isomorphisms.

Comment: @Thorgott I think that we mean different things. I mean that the **induced morphism** must be an isomorphism. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that we have :

- a functor $D\colon \mathcal{D}\to \mathbf{Red}_{\Sigma,\Sigma'}T$
- a colimit cocone $(\delta_d\colon D(d)\to B)_{d\in\mathbf{Ob}(\mathcal{D})}$ in $\mathbf{Red}_{\Sigma,\Sigma'}T$
- a colimit cocone $(\overline{\delta_d}\colon i(D(d))\to A)_{d\in\mathbf{Ob}(\mathcal{D})}$ in $\mathbf{Str}\Sigma$

where $i\colon \mathbf{Red}_{\Sigma,\Sigma'}T \to \mathbf{Str}\Sigma$ denotes the inclusion functor.

Then saying that $i$ preserves colimits means that $(i(\delta_d)\colon i(D(d))\to i(B))_{d\in\mathbf{Ob}(\mathcal{D})}$ is a colimit cocone in $\mathbf{Str}\Sigma$. Since it is a cocone, there is an induced morphism $h\colon A\to i(B)$ with the property that $h\overline{\delta_d}=i(\delta_d)$ for all $d$; and then $(i(\delta_d)\colon i(D(d))\to i(B))_{d\in\mathbf{Ob}(\mathcal{D})}$ is a colimit cocone if and only if $h$ is an isomorphism.

Indeed, if $(i(\delta_d))_d$ is also a colimit cocone, then we can simply use the universal property to get a morphism $h'\colon i(B)\to A$ with the property that $h'i(\delta_d)=\overline{\delta_d}$, and check that $h$ and $h'$ are inverse of one another. Conversely, if $h$ is an isomorphism, and we have some cocone $(\lambda_d\colon i(D(d))\to C)_d$, we get a unique induced morphism $g\colon A\to C$, and then a unique induced morphism $gh^{-1}\colon i(B)\to C$.

Comment: Dear Arnaud, I understand your explanation but for the thing that you have used an **arbitrary** isomorphism but [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) on the page 137 below $5.22$ the say "...it must be isomorphic in a **particular** way". Where have you loosed this particularity ?

Comment: @user122424 My isomorphism is not arbitrary at all, it is the morphism induced by the image of the colimit cone, so it is uniquely determined. It's the same morphism as in Leinster's book.

Comment: Dear Arnaud, I shall have more question but for now this one: $h'\colon B\to A$ should really be $h'\colon i(B)\to A$ ?

Comment: Yes, good catch (corrected).